# Linux parted 5 Partitions

Tags: linux

In Linux I have a Disk with 1 GB. I would like to create 5 Partitions with each 200MB using msdos table.

I know that I can create max. 4 primary partitions.

For my task I think I need 3 primary, 1 extended and 1 logical.

I can create 3 primary each 200MB 1 extended 200MB but the 5th logical does not have 200MB. And if I use the command lsblk my extended Disk has '1k' ? Is it possible to create 5 Disks each 200MB ?

Comment: *"I think I need 3 primary, 1 extended and 1 logical"* -- No, that only gets you four usable partitions for filesystems (or swap).  You can only allocate logical partitions in an extended partition.  You cannot install a filesystem in an extended partition.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter stated, the extended partition does not host a file system, it hosts any number of logical partitions with most operating systems limiting a total of 15 partitions. You would need 3 primary partitions, an extended partition which should be the last primary partition, then 2 logical partitions for your filesystems.

Further reading:

http://www.howtogeek.com/184659/beginner-geek-hard-disk-partitions-explained/

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/understanding-hard-disk-partitions/

Note this is all under MBR partitioning, there is also GPT partitioning which allows for up to 128 partitions but requires UEFI to contain a bootable filesystem.